# While Scheduling Task with Celery in Djano Backend is good RabbitMQTT or django-celery-result?

Tags: django, architecture, rabbitmq, celery, scheduled-tasks

**here is my task.py:**

```
@shared_task
def schedule_task(subscription_id):
    subscription = Subscriptions.objects.get(id=subscription_id)
    # Perform the task for the subscription
    # ...
    pass

@shared_task
def remove_task(subscription_id):
    # Task to remove the subscription-related task
    # ...
    pass
```

**here is my model.py with signals in it:**

```
def generate_dispatch_uid():
    timestamp = timezone.now().isoformat()
    unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    dispatch_uid = f"{unique_id}_{timestamp}"
    return dispatch_uid

def default_billing_date():
    return date.today() + timedelta(days=7)

class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscription_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_yearly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_date = models.DateField(default=default_billing_date)
    @staticmethod
    def schedule_subscription_task(subscription):
        if subscription.is_yearly:
            # Schedule task to run after 12 months and +6 days
            schedule_date = subscription.billing_date + timedelta(days=372)
            schedule_task.apply_async(args=[subscription.id], eta=schedule_date)
        else:
            # Schedule task to run monthly, billing_date + 6 days
            schedule_date = subscription.billing_date + timedelta(days=6)
            schedule_task.apply_async(args=[subscription.id], eta=schedule_date)

    @staticmethod
    def remove_subscription_task(subscription):
        remove_task.apply_async(args=[subscription.id])



@receiver(post_save, sender=Subscriptions, dispatch_uid=generate_dispatch_uid())
def create_subscription_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Subscriptions.schedule_subscription_task(instance)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Subscriptions,dispatch_uid=generate_dispatch_uid())
def delete_subscription_task(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Subscriptions.remove_subscription_task(instance)
```

**Here is my celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from MyProject.config import RabbitMQTT_Broker, RabbitMQTT_Result_backend

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

# Create a new Celery app.
app = Celery('MyProject')

# Configure Celery to use Redis.
app.conf.broker_url = RabbitMQTT_Broker
app.conf.result_backend = RabbitMQTT_Result_backend

# Load configuration from Django settings.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Discover tasks modules in your apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

well my task will be executed when a subscription model have any event like new subscription add or existing subscription remove.

If the subscription is yearly the task will be executing each year on that date and if susbscirption is monthly the task will going to execute each month.

When the susbcription is deleted the corresponding task will be deleted as well

Now tell me what is better in my case django-celery-results or RabbitMQT

Also guide me on any code modifications if needed.

Now you have good idea of my case.

I want a Robust and Reliable Task Scheduling Mechanism with Best Fault Tolerance.